# Can't program bareduino. "avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding"

Tags: uploading, atmega328

I've built a bareduino. The blink sketch that it came preprogrammed with worked. I was also able to program the ATmega328 by putting it into a arduino uno.

What I can't do is upload a sketch directly. I've tried both of the methods described here: https://www.virtuabotix.com/bareduino328-programming-guide/

I've used FTDI before and I know that my drivers work. I've tried suggestions from many forums and after 3 hours I'm running out of options.

The issue seems to be the reset pin. But the fixes here have not worked. I must admit I'm confused about how to un-ground the reset pin. I tried unplugging the power. When I tried to upload with FTDI I had a capacitor... so shouldn't that fix this error?

Verbose Error Code:

```
Sketch uses 7,920 bytes (24%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32,256 bytes.
Global variables use 383 bytes (18%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1,665 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2,048 bytes.
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -P/dev/cu.usbmodem1d11 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:/var/folders/r9/t7hwvgjx1kz18v8j60_kp_vh0000gn/T/build7068227750495702499.tmp/webclient.cpp.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Apr 14 2015 at 16:30:25
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/Users/futurebird/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbmodem1d11
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

Comment: What are your fuses set to? Where is this capacitor? It should be between RTS on the FTDI cable and Reset, and Reset should have a 10k pull-up resistor to +5V. Which bootloader is on the chip?

Comment: It's like this: https://virtuabotix-virtuabotixllc.netdna-ssl.com/core/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/arduinoserialpinout_small.jpg

It has a uno bootloader

Comment: What are the fuses set to? If you don't know you can find out with my [Signature detector sketch](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11633).

Comment: Also try manually resetting the bareduino with a grounded wire shortly before or after you begin the upload. If that works, then the fault is with the the auto-reset circuit.